# Monitoring ActiveMQ queues without an open jmx port

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic, message, jmx

I am new to JMS and am working with an existing ActiveMQ installation. I am aware of the Admin interface that ActiveMQ provides, however access to it is restricted in order to prevent developers reading the actual message content (data protection). I was wondering if there is a way to monitor the message queues without JMX ports being open (they were disabled due to security policies). All we'd like to know is statistics like build up of messages on queues, which queues are active, have active consumers, etc.

I went through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551846/activemq-get-queue-size-without-using-jmx-jms) as it seemed closest to what I'm looking for, but as far as I understood, the Statistics plug-in for Active MQ described there depends upon the JMX port being open. Is this true ?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can password protect the JMX ports so JMS users do not have access

Option 2: Using the statistics plugin requires the management beans being registered, but you don't have to expose it via a TCP/IP port. It is a Java setting, not an ActiveMQ one.

ref: [Configure JMX Agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html)